play audio background upon imges in PageView appearing errors?
I want to make an quotes app with background audio in PageView with images when scrolling up
then next audio play, if the user standing on specific quote the crossponding audio repeating continuously untill the user scroll up if scroll
then play nextAudio for static usage quotes single strings are appering
but did not work pretty
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:just_audio_background/just_audio_background.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

// import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AudioPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioPlayerScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AudioPlayerScreen> createState() => _AudioPlayerScreenState();
}

class _AudioPlayerScreenState extends State<AudioPlayerScreen> {
  late AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  List<String> dataStored = ['ali ahmad', 'noman', 'shabaz', 'Ali Akbar'];
  int currentIndex = 0; // Track the current index for audio playback
  bool isRepeating = true; // Flag to control audio looping
  List<String> audioPaths = ['motivational', 'inspirational'];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
      ..onPlayerStateChanged.listen((playerState) {
        if (playerState == PlayerStateSteam.COMPLETED) {
          if (isRepeating) {
            _playAudio(currentIndex); // Repeat audio if looping enabled
          }
        }
      });
    _playAudio(currentIndex); // Start playing the initial audio
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

 void _playAudio(int index) async {
  final String audioPath = 'assets/audio/${audioPaths[index]}.mp3';
  await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(AssetAudioSource.asset(audioPath));
  await audioPlayer.play();
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('example'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: dataStored.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              const Image(
                width: 500.0,
                image: AssetImage('assets/roadImg.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    dataStored[index],
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Controls(audioPlayer: audioPlayer),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.63,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('clicked');
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.comment, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
        onPageChanged: (newIndex) {
          if (currentIndex != newIndex) {
            isRepeating = false; // Stop repeating when page changes
            _playAudio(newIndex);
            currentIndex = newIndex;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Rather then this make a playlist with audio source and pass it directly to AudioPlayer. And on page change use seekTo(position,pageViewIndex)
final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

// Define the playlist
  final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
    // Start loading next item just before reaching it
    useLazyPreparation: true,
    // Customise the shuffle algorithm
    shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder(),
    // Specify the playlist items
    children: [audiosources],
  );

Future<void> initAudio() async {
    await player.setAudioSource(
      playlist,
      initialIndex: 0,
      initialPosition: Duration.zero,
    );
    await player
        .setLoopMode(LoopMode.one); // Set playlist to loop (off|all|one)
  }

and then use this to play other video
await player.seek(position, index: pageIndex);
if (!player.playing) {
       await player.play();
     }

or you can also use player.seekToNext() depending upon your use case.
Also save this position for each audio ,such that when you go to previous page, you can start from the point where you left

these errors are appear..!
audio playback error
unknown assets
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: (0) Source error
E/flutter (15600): #0      AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:869:9)
E/flutter (15600): 
E/flutter (15600): #1      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1465:28)
E/flutter (15600): 

The error is happening because you are using method that is used to fetch  online audio but as you are getting it from assets use AudioSource.asset() method not the AudioSource.uri() method

if i want to random genrate audio then
what should to do?
because i pass two paths but first play again and again
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
useLazyPreparation: true,
shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder(),
children: [
AudioSource.asset('assets:///assets/audio/inspirational.mp3'),
AudioSource.asset('assets:///assets/audio/motivational.mp3'),
],
);

the reason is because onPageChange you are only changing the page, not the audio, so on onchange do this
await player.seek(position, index: pageIndex); if (!player.playing) {        await player.play();      }
For this you need to have same no. of audio in playlist as pages in pageview

or if you just want to play this two audio uniformally on pageChange  use player.seekToNext() this way only 2 audio will play one by one for each page change

here my whole component:

// import 'dart:io';

// import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
  List<String> dataStored = ['ali ahmad', 'noman', 'shabaz', 'Ali Akbar'];
  int currentIndex = 0;

  final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
    useLazyPreparation: true,
    shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder(),
    children: [
      AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('assets://assets/audio/motivational.mp3')),
      AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('assets://assets/audio/inspirational.mp3')),
    ],
  );
  @override
  void initState() {
    initAudio();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> initAudio() async {
    await player.setAudioSource(
      playlist,
      initialIndex: 0,
      initialPosition: Duration.zero,
    );
    await player
        .setLoopMode(LoopMode.one); // Set playlist to loop (off|all|one)

    await player.seek(Duration.zero, index: currentIndex);
    if (!player.playing) {
      await player.play();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('example'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: dataStored.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              const Image(
                width: 500.0,
                image: AssetImage('assets/roadImg.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    dataStored[index],
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Controls(audioPlayer: audioPlayer),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.63,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('clicked');
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.comment, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
        onPageChanged: (newIndex) {
          if (currentIndex != newIndex) {
            currentIndex = newIndex;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

